# Unable to get extra from intent

Tags: android-intent

Alway get null value when using getextra method,I am adding extra on one activity and receiving on the other activity, my code is

```
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
    String filePath="";

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(TagActivity.this,AddnewNoteActivity.class);
    if(requestCode==1)
    {

    }
    else if(requestCode==2)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {  
            intent1.putExtra("path", data.getData());
            intent1.setType("image/*");
        }

    }
    else if(requestCode==3)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            intent1.putExtra("path", data.getData());
            intent1.setType("audio/*");
        }

    }
        startActivity(intent1);

}
```

on receiving side

```
    if(imageUri==null) 
    {

       extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        if (extras != null) {
            String Path;
            Path= extras.getString("path");
            imageUri = Uri.parse(Path);
        }           
    }
```

Nuth every time receive null in Path, Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem resolved as

intent1.putExtra("path", data.getData()**.tostring()**); //on sender side